# Why does japanese filenames not show on ubuntu server and samba?

Tags: mount, fat32, filename, japanese

I've installed japanese fonts

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-takao-mincho
```

and I mounted my drive specifying utf8

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdc1 /media/HERMES -o uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137
```

but japanese file names show up as ??? in terminal and on my samba share, it shows up as numbers+characters.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to use `cifs` instead of `vfat` ?  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=288534

Comment: I followed that guide but console hangs if I try to access the drive after the mount. `sudo mount -t cifs //orion/HERMES /media/HERMES -o guest,rw,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem, although I don't understand why it didn't resolve the japanese characters with the standard mount command, I found that pmount works well. Hope this helps others!

Unmount Auto Mounted USB drives

```
pumount /media/usb0
```

Mount Manually USB Drives

```
pmount /dev/sdc1 HERMES
```

Comment: The drives were auto mounted but I couldn't read the file names still. After dismounting and remounting with pmount, everything is viewable in command line and in samba shares.